# Node internationalisation not working inside Jade views (node i18n)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, internationalization

I've been using the [i18n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n) Node module for internationalisation. In the root I initialise the module as follows:

```
i18n.configure({
  locales: ['en', 'nl'],
  register: global,
  directory: path.join(__dirname, 'locales'),
  defaultLocale: 'en',
  objectNotation: true
});

app.use(i18n.init);
```

This module already registers the translation function (`__()`) as a global. However, this function doesn't work, so I decided to pass it down so that the method is available in my controllers and views:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.user = req.session.user || null;
  res.locals.formatDate = (data) => data ? format(data, process.env.DATE_FORMAT) : null;
  res.locals.__ = res.__ = () => i18n.__.apply(req, arguments);
  req.setLocale('en')

  next();
});
```

It works fine in controllers. I use `req.__('string-to-translate')` and this translates as desired.

However, when I try to use the exact same function in my views rendered with pug/jade, it returns me `undefined`.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?